# How do I get the path and info of Dropbox files using python API

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am using the python Dropbox API and I am trying to get the `path` and `media file` of each file so I can reorganize my Dropbox account.

Presently, my code is below and I in testing, the `media_info` has no output (these are all video files) and in reading the documentation I can't figure out how to list my path.

So, I would like to get:

1. path of file
2. Media info of file

**app.py**

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('xxxxxx')
result = dbx.files_list_folder("", recursive=True)
file_list = []

i = 1
for entry in dbx.files_list_folder("").entries:
    if isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
        print(entry.name)
        print(entry.size / 1000000)
        print(entry.media_info)
        print(f'The  number is {i}')
        i= i + 1
```

**output**

```
sci_2003_toothbrush_injury_study.mov
215.624412
None
The  number is 1
edu_2003_stem_saturdays.mov
457.252114
None
The  number is 2
boo_202004_eduardo_porter.mov
2889.928171
None
The  number is 3
```

Comment: What does `type(entry)` gives you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For get full path use instance ***dropbox.files.FileMetadata*** for example:

```py
import dropbox
from dropbox.files import FolderMetadata


def printListFilesRecursive():
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('XXXXXXXX')

    # Use recursive=True for scan recursive folder.
    for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('', recursive=True).entries:
        # Use instance FileMetadata for get more information of entry
        if isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            print(entry.path_display)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    printListFilesRecursive()
```

Output:

```sh
/PokemonGo Maps 1.0 Versión original/transform.py
/PokemonGo Maps 1.0 Versión original/transform.pyc
/PokemonGo Maps 1.0 Versión original/npm-debug.log
/Screenshots/Screenshot 2016-10-19 17.01.50.png
/Screenshots/Screenshot 2016-10-19 17.02.08(3).png
```